# JFreeChart Dynamic Scatter Chart

Tags: java, graph

I have a model that consists of a 100 'agents' that change their x and y coordinates randomly. I use JFreeChart scatter chart to represent agents' locations.

```
package jfreecharttest;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

public class ScatterChartExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Dynamic chart");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(
                frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        DynamicChartPanel panel = new DynamicChartPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        JButton button = new JButton("Start");

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                if (panel.isStarted()) {
                    panel.stop();
                    button.setText("Start");
                } else {
                    panel.start();
                    button.setText("Stop");
                }
            }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(button);        

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class DynamicChartPanel extends JPanel{

    private final ChartPanel content;
    private final XYSeries agentLocations;
    private final RandomModel model;
    private final Timer timer;
    private boolean started;

    public DynamicChartPanel() {

        agentLocations = new XYSeries("Agent locations");
        this.model = new RandomModel();

        updateAgentLocationSeries();

        content = new ChartPanel(ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(
                "Dynamic chart", "x", "y",
                new XYSeriesCollection(agentLocations)));
        this.add(content);
        initializeChart();

        timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                model.iterate();
                updateAgentLocationSeries();
            }
        });
        started = false;
    }

    private void initializeChart() {

        int padding = 10;

        XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) content.getChart().getPlot();

        NumberAxis domain = (NumberAxis) xyPlot.getDomainAxis();
        domain.setRange(model.getxMin() - padding, model.getxMax() + padding);

        NumberAxis range = (NumberAxis) xyPlot.getRangeAxis();
        range.setRange(model.getyMin() - padding, model.getyMax() + padding);
    }

    public void start() {
        timer.start();
        started = true;
    }

    public void stop() {
        timer.stop();
        started = false;
    }

    public boolean isStarted() {
        return started;
    }

    private void updateAgentLocationSeries() {
        agentLocations.clear();
        for (Agent agent : model.getAgents()) {
            agentLocations.add(agent.getX(), agent.getY());
        }
    }
}

class RandomModel {

    private final Random random;

    private final List<Agent> agents;
    private final int agentCount;

    /*
       Space size
     */    
    private final int xMin;
    private final int yMin;
    private final int xMax;
    private final int yMax;

    private final int moveRange;

    public RandomModel() {

        random = new Random();
        agents = new ArrayList<>();

        agentCount = 100;
        xMin = 0;
        xMax = 100;
        yMin = 0;
        yMax = 100;
        moveRange = 4;

        initializeAgents();
    }

    public List<Agent> getAgents() {
        return agents;
    }

    public int getxMin() {
        return xMin;
    }

    public int getyMin() {
        return yMin;
    }

    public int getxMax() {
        return xMax;
    }

    public int getyMax() {
        return yMax;
    }    

    public void iterate() {
        moveAgents();
    }

    /*
      Initially place each agent into a free random location
    */

    private void initializeAgents() {

        for (int i = 0; i < agentCount; i++) {

            int xPosition = random.nextInt(getxMax());
            int yPosition = random.nextInt(getyMax());

            while (locationTaken(xPosition, yPosition)) {
                xPosition = random.nextInt((getxMax() - getxMin() + 1) + getxMin());
                yPosition = random.nextInt((getyMax() - getyMin() + 1) + getyMin());
            }

            getAgents().add(new Agent(xPosition, yPosition));
        }
    }

    /*
      Every agent changes its coordinates within the move range
    */

    private void moveAgents() {
        for (Agent agent : getAgents()) {
            int xMinimum = agent.getX() - moveRange;
            int xMaximum = agent.getX() + moveRange;
            int yMinimum = agent.getY() - moveRange;
            int yMaximum = agent.getY() + moveRange;
            int x = wrapCoordinate(
                    random.nextInt((xMaximum - xMinimum) + 1) + xMinimum, 
                    getxMin(), getxMax());
            int y = wrapCoordinate(
                    random.nextInt((yMaximum - yMinimum) + 1) + yMinimum, 
                    getyMin(), getyMax());
            agent.setX(x);
            agent.setY(y);
        }
    }

    /*
       Wrap number around min and max
       If min is 0 and max is 100, 101 becomes 0 and -1 becomes 100
     */

    private int wrapCoordinate(int number, int min, int max) {
        int rangeSize = max - min + 1;
        if (number < min) {
            number += rangeSize * ((min - number) / rangeSize + 1);
        }
        return min + (number - min) % rangeSize;
    }

    /*
       Check if a location is taken by an agent
     */

    private boolean locationTaken(int xPosition, int yPosition) {
        for (Agent agent : getAgents()) {
            if (agent.getX() == xPosition && agent.getY() == yPosition) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class Agent {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Agent(int xPosition, int yPosition)
    {
        x = xPosition;
        y = yPosition;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

No specific questions about the code, except maybe about performance. JFreeChart seemed the quickest way to get a dynamic chart. I've seen related questions on Stack Overflow so others are using it for animating charts, but I'm not sure if I should use it or maybe use other tools like LibGDX or something else I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `locationTaken` is a big performance bottleneck as it iterates through all points whenever you're adding a new one. Depending on the size of the fields (currently 0-100, 0-100), it is also very low probability for any collision.

I believe the probability for *no* collisions on the very last generation is something like

\$(1 - \frac{1}{101^2})^{100} = 0.990244456...\$

This makes the probability for a collision less than one percent.

Also, the first randomization you're not using the min-values of the X and Y bounds.

When you use the min and max values for the randomization, `+ getXMin()` should be outside the `random.nextInt` parameter, otherwise you'll just produce a value from 0 to an even higher number.

If you still want to maintain collision-detection, despite the very low probability of collisions, you can use a `HashSet<Point>` to check if the values exist already, like below.

```
Set<Point> added = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < agentCount; i++) {
    int x;
    int y;
    do {
         x = random.nextInt(getXMax() - getXMin() + 1) + getXMin();
         y = random.nextInt(getYMax() - getYMin() + 1) + getYMin();
    }
    while (!added.add(new Point(x, y)));
}
```

---

I am not familiar with JFreeChart, but it seems to me that the `updateAgentLocationSeries()` method can be modified to instead of removing the locations and then re-adding them with new values, it can loop through the locations and update them. See the [XYSeries.addOrUpdate method](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYSeries.html#addOrUpdate%28org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataItem%29). If you use this you will have to use `XYDataItem` instead of your current class though.

---

A better name for `Agent` would be `Point`, and that class is usable enough to be a public class in a separate file.

I also don't like names like `getyMax`, the character after `get` should be uppercase. I'd prefer `getYMax`.

---

The way you're currently using `private final int moveRange;` and many others is by giving them a fixed value in the constructor. If you don't intend on providing that parameter using constructor arguments, you should change these fields to constants, such as:

```
private static final int MOVE_RANGE = 4;
```

---

I have to say though that overall your code is very readable and easy to understand, and I really like that you're using `final` excessively! Good job.

Comment: The locationTaken() implementation is a bit naive. I've been thinking of using a matrix for location lookup, but using a HashSet seems the simplest way. I will add a couple of fields to the Agent class later, maybe separate the classes and add a field of type Point to the Agent class. moveRange and space dimensions are given, will use constants. I was probably unwittingly trying to make the code more general than it needs to be. I used NetBeans refactoring to generate getxMax() and getyMax(), the names did seem a bit odd. Both mistakes with Random noted.